# How to resolve the Android error “method setSupportActionBar in class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am making an android app solving with various options but always get an error.

Here is the code :

activity_set.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sets"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="16dp"/>
        <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

SetActivity.java

```
public class SetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
private GridView gridView;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set);

        //Toolbar toolbar;
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(16);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
 [![Error][1]][1]
```